# getting second newest version of source code

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I’m new to Mercurial. I’m trying to clone the second newest commit from the web interface, and everything I’ve red says I need to enter the revision number. However, the web interface only shows “age”, “author”, “description” and at the bottom has “rev 27: (0) tip”
I know which one I want based on the description, and it’s the second from the top. How do I get it? I assume when I did `hg clone https://...` it got the newest version

Comment: Personally I'd just `hg clone` the whole repo (or at least that branch) and then `hg update -r <whatever>`, perhaps based on `hg log` output. (Or perhaps `hg update -r -1` or `hg update -r -2`).

Comment: @DaveC that's what I'm not sure of, would it be `hg update -r -1` or `hg update -r -2` (or `-r -0`...)

Answer (score 2):

Just clone the whole repository, then update to the second newest commit with `hg update -r -2`.

Note that if you have branches, the "second newest commit" may be on a different branch.  In that case, you can list the latest two changes on a particular branch with `hg log -b <branch> -l 2`, then `hg update -r <rev>` to the older of the two changesets listed for that branch.

Another way to get the 2nd newest commit on a branch is the following syntax:

```
hg update <branch>^
```

For example:

```
hg update my_branch^
```

Note on Windows `^` is an escape character for the console, so it must be doubled for one literal `^`:

```
hg update my_branch^^
```

Another way to get the first ancestor of a branch tip is:

```
hg update my_branch~1
```

See also `hg help revsets` and `hg help revisions`.

Comment: Ok I'm new to version control and didn't understand when I clone the repository it gets the whole history and not just the `n-th` commit.